# Using Firebase to list and sort records from greatest to least and print to HTML table body

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of players and their accumulated winnings in firebase. Each  record will be added to the  from least to greatest.

```
<table id="toptenwinners" class="table table-hover table-sm">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Rank</th>
<th>Player</th>
<th>Earnings</th>
<th>Tokens</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>  <-- start of insert
<th scope="row">1</th>  <-- number generated after sort
<td>John Q Public</td> <-- from "player" in firebase
<td>552,133</td>       <-- from "total earnings" in firebase
<td>1,212,808</td>     <-- from "tokens" in firebase
</tr> <-- end of insert
 ..next record
```

The routine written doesn't seem to work well for this simple application.

```
dataRef.on('player',function(toptenwinners){

var toptenwinnersHTML = "";

toptenwinners.forEach(function(firebaseOrderReference){
var toptenwinners = dataRef.val();
console.log(toptenwinners); 
var tableofwinners = 

<tr>
<th scope="row">1</th>  
<td>' + player + '</td> 
<td>' + t_earnings + '</td>       
<td>' + t_token + '</td>     
</tr>;

toptenwinnersHTML = toptenwinnersHTML + tableofwinners;
});

$('#toptentable').html(toptenwinnersHTML);
});
```

I'm wondering if there is a simpler way (using jquery) to list all the 'players' in the DB, their earnings and tokens cleanly into the . Add a way to sort from highest tokens (t_tokens) to least, then number each "row" (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4..) based on the sort.

```
Sample HTML Output:
Rank Name       Earnings Tokens
1    Spongebob  55,222   1,234,555
2    DarthVadar 88,010   555,213
3    PacMan     12,123   120,111
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sad how questions go stale around here. Anywho, figured it out. The trick was in using the data.ref().once function to list all the content of the DB then gracefully pass the results (on each iteration) to the html table format.

Worked like a charm..

```
function listthechamps() {

let y = 0
$("#tableChampion").empty();

var database = firebase.database();
database.ref().once('value', function (snapshot) {
if (snapshot.exists()) {
var content = '';
snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
y++
var val = data.val();
content += '<tr>';
content += '<td>' + y + '</td>';
content += '<td>' + val.player + '</td>';
content += '<td>' + val.t_earnings + '</td>';
content += '<td>' + val.t_token + '</td>';
content += '</tr>';
});
$('#tableChampion').append(content);
}
});
}
```